# Android studio dependencies download

Tags: android-studio

I want to know how to download dependencies from Android studio website and not from the IDE.
My laptop is small and has minimal space.
Please how can I do this without doing it from Android studio IDE.
And I can't do anything without these dependencies.

I installed android studio and tried downloading the dependencies, but due to limited space and I couldn't.
So I tried downloading it into my external disc, but it still would download into my internal disc.
How can I download dependencies into my external disc.

Comment: What are these dependencies you are talking about? Do you mean SDK?

Comment: These dependencies are those that pop up for download after installing android studio

Comment: Maybe a screenshot would help. I think you mean the  SDK. If it is, you can download it separately and place it in any other location

Comment: Please how can I download it and place it in any location. That is how do I go about doing it.

Comment: In the link you can download command line tools whitch let you download and install SDK without android studio https://developer.android.com/studio 
https://developer.android.com/tools/sdkmanager